# How do i create an arraylist of values from a nested HashMap in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, kruskals-algorithm

I have written my code using a nested HashMap and i'm trying to figure out how to put all values pointed by the key of the inner map into an ArrayList, in order to properly sort it.
My map looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> vlist;
```

My idea was to create another HashMap with same key and value of the inner map shown before,
then populate it in this way.

```
HashMap<String, Double> vlistValues = new HashMap<>(vlist.values());
```

I get a compilation error, and i can figure out that the compiler doesn't know that the value of my outer map is a map itself, but reading the hashmap documentation i didn't find a method that fits my situation.

Basically i want to put all the values of the inner map declared here`HashMap<String ,HashMap<String, Double>> vlist;` to a list like this`ArrayList<Double> listOfValues;`

If it wasn't clear i'm totally new to programming :-)

I'll show an example:
My map `HashMap<String, Hashmap<String,Double>>` represents the adjacency list of a weighted graph. I need to sort all the edges (as i'm trying to implement Kruskal's algorithm) and my idea was to put all the weights in an list  doing something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> vertexList; //all the vertices of the graph
ArrayList<Double> weights; 
HashMap<String, String> orderedEdges = new HashMap<>(); //here i put ordered edges
double min = Collections.min(weights); //i use this double to keep track of the minimum element in weights

  for(String vertex1 : vertexlist){
    makeSet(vertex1);
    for(String vertex2 : ajacents(vertex1)){
      if(getEdgeWeight(v1,v2) <= min){ //method "getEdgeWeight" is to retrieve weight of an edge
        orderedEdges.put(v1,v2);
        min = getEdgeWeight(v1,v2) 
        weights.remove(min) //i'm not sure this line is correct
      }
    }
  }
```

Looking at some pseudo-code online i saw that it is able to make the disjoint sets and ordering the edges in the same for-loop. Probably my code is not efficent but i really don't know how to sort the edges without visiting all the graph. Ps i cannot use a priority queue but i perfectly know that what i'm trying to do is something similar

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you said:

*Basically i want to put all the values of the inner map declared here `HashMap<String ,HashMap<String, Double>> vlist`; to a list like this `ArrayList<Double> listOfValues`*

Here is the sample hashMap.

```
      Map<String, Map<String, Double>> mm = Map.of("A",
            Map.of("R", 1.2, "S", 3.4, "T", 3.8),
            "B",
            Map.of("S", 9.8, "V", 2.8),
            "Z",
            Map.of("P", 22.3));

      System.out.println(mm);
```

Here's the map.

> {Z={P=22.3}, B={S=9.8, V=2.8}, A={T=3.8, S=3.4, R=1.2}}

To convert to a `List` of doubles you can do this.  Get a `stream` of the `values` (which are the inner maps), and then `combine all the values in those maps` into a common stream via a `flatMap` and then collect to a `List`.

```java
      List<Double> dubs =
            mm.values().stream().flatMap(k -> k.values().stream()).collect(
                  Collectors.toList());

      System.out.println(dubs);
```

Here's the list.

> [22.3, 9.8, 2.8, 3.8, 3.4, 1.2]

If you want a `Map<String, List<Doubles>>` where the String is the key of the outer Map you can do this. Create a `stream` of `entrySet` of the `outer map` and pass it to a `collector`.  The `collector` creates a map using the `outer maps key` and then takes the values of the `inner map` (which is a collection) and passes them as an argument to `ArrayList<>` to create a `List`.

```
  Map<String, List<Double>> mapOfDubs =
        mm.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
              e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue().values())));

  System.out.println(mapOfDubs);
```

Here's the map.

> {A=[1.2, 3.4, 3.8], B=[2.8, 9.8], Z=[22.3]}

Answer (score 0):

From a map like `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> vlist;` you have

- `vlist.keys()` a `List<String>` , which contains all the keys
- `vlist.values()` a `List<HashMap<String, Double>>`, which contains **all** the map that are a value

To get a particular `List<Double>` you need a key, so select the inner map from which you'll read the doubles

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> outer = ...; // don't call a map *list*
HashMap<String, Double> inner  = outer.get("mykey");
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<>(inner.values()); // as values() returns a Collection
```

Comment: Ok, thx so i need a specific key or i can do it for each key in the inner map?

Comment: @flatbrain seems you do not understand the structure, a key of of the outer map point to a Map, a key of an inner map point to a Double value, just one, maybe you coul edit your post with an example of content to explain more ? Also 'new to programming' doesn't fit very well with "access values in a nested map" ;)